# Run Windows Program With Flags / Parameters

Tags: windows-7

I have an executable that I would like to run with a flag:

```
C:\path\executable.exe -a-flag=flagstuff
```

I know I am able to make shortcuts and batch files run the executable with flags automatically, but I do not want to have to hunt down and set every single shortcut and set the flag.  And even if I did that, applications that set that executable as the default application for something won't run the application with flags.

How can I make it so this executable will always run with a flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could edit the registry settings of that particular executable so it always runs with the parameters you set. Below, is a related question regarding always running firefox.exe with some arguments on windows xp:

[How to set default parameters for an application?](https://superuser.com/questions/12230/how-to-set-default-parameters-for-an-application)

I believe, the registry path shouldn't be much different on windows 7 as well. i.e. always something like

> \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApplication\shell\open\command

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut, right click, and in the target line, add your flag.

Here's a screenshot of someone adding a "-stdout" flag: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you set that shortcut as, for example,  the default application for a file type?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I was adding my flag within the target filename's quotation marks, and it needed to be outside of them.