Launch a program by double clicking a file, **with options**
I associated .tex files with TeXworks. When I double click on a .tex file, TeXworks opens as I want it to.
But I TeXworks to start with arguments, specifically texworks -stylesheet /pathto/mystyle.css to enable dark mode.
How can I double click on a .tex file and launch TeXworks with these arguments?

No need to use HTML formatting here. Just press your RETURN/Enter key to add normal line spaces. Now, what research have you done and what have you tried regarding this? I would guess that you'd need to modify the path in the Registry to add the arguments you want, and this might be quite easy, or a majorly difficult pain.

Just a quick web search showed a few duplicates on this site going back through several Windows OSes: https://www.bing.com/search?q=add+arguments+to+filetype+default+open+applicatiton

Also this one: https://superuser.com/questions/12230/how-to-set-default-parameters-for-an-application
